# Reference cell by identifier(not address) between sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

**Scenario:**
I have a programmatically generated Excel (`.xlsx`) document with hundreds of rows of numerical values, in multiple sheets. Each sheet has total/subtotal values (using summation). The last sheet is a summary sheet that adds up these totals using `INDIRECT` and referencing the sheet and cell addresses (eg "'11-November-2018'.D13").

**Problem**:
Once generated programmatically, the formulae and functions are set. However, this document must be editable i.e. deletion of rows in any sheet should be possible such that changes in totals and subtotals in respective sheets should reflect in the summary sheet. However, once a row is deleted, the total/subtotal cell address changes, and the `INDIRECT` function in the Summary sheet fails.

**Desired:**
Is there a way to reference cells between sheets such that deletion of rows in one sheet reflect the changes correctly in the Summary sheet?

Find test workbook [HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r9H6LaVpa8If7r7_tFdDsOin3C0y9tQb/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Why are you using INDIRECT here? In your example workbook, you have, in D7 of Sheet4, the formula `=INDIRECT("Sheet1!B29")`, but why is this preferred to simply `=Sheet1!B29`?

Comment: You can use `INDIRECT` when you don't want the reference to change when you delete/insert cells.  If you want the change, then use the direct reference, as @XORLX said.

Comment: @XORLX Thanks for the solution. Me having limited knowledge of Excel I assumed the addresses do not change automatically, and started with INDIRECT. I tried by removing `INDIRECT`, and it now works as desired.

Comment: Ok, good to know. And you're welcome!